# Carbonation drops in cider

Tags: carbonation, cider

First posted question here so sorry if I've missed a previous answer. I've been trying out a secondary ferment in old champagne bottles of a barrel fermented cider. When decanting into the bottles I have been careful to exclude all sediment from the first ferment and the brew is nice and clear. To start things going again I've used either apple juice or sugar. I'm very happy with the carbonation, but the fermentation is leaving dead yeast as a sediment which clouds up the cider once opened. I was thinking that a way around this might be to use carbonation drops to get the fizz hence no sediment. What's the quality of the bubbles like in terms of size and how do they last in the glass if using drops?
Thank you.

Answer (score 5):

Carbonation drops are just aliquoted doses of sugar.  They still carbonate by the action of yeast in the bottle.  I don't think carb drops will solve the problem you describe.

Comment: OK thought they were too good to be true! Is the only way forward to pressure keg and then bottle once fermentation is complete?

Comment: No - it is possible to pour the cider carefully from the bottle into a glass and leave the yeast/etc in the bottle. if one wants "industrial cider" then one has to filter it, carbonate it and pressure bottle it.